# flutter - how to see the file that saved on the local storage?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am debugging an app. The apps save some file on the local storage, I want to see the file that on the local storage in order to debug it? is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if you could provide some pieces of code so that we can help you best :)

I think you could write a fonction that loads and read from you localFile, and call it when you widget is initialized :

```
Future<String> read() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;

    // Read the file.
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    print(contents);
    return contents;
  } catch (e) {
    // error catching
  }
}
```

hope it helps !